Selection between classes at runtime for instantiation
I want to construct an object of a type which is selected at runtime based on an enum class value. The classes A and B have multiple constructors with various numbers of arguments which may be used at runtime. I have attempted this problem by trying to write a factory method returning a shared_ptr to the base class.
Here is my ill-formed attempt:
enum class Type
{
    A,
    B // C, etc
};

struct Base{};

struct A : public Base
{
    A(const int a) { std::cout << "A::A(int)"; }
    A(double d) { std::cout << "A::A(double)"; }
    A(int a, double d) { std::cout << "A::A(int,double)"; }
};

struct B : public Base
{
    B(int i, double d) { std::cout << "B::B(double)"; }
    B(int a, double d, double dd) { std::cout << "B::B(int,double, double)"; }
};

template <typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<Base> make_Type(Type t, Args &&...args)
{
    if (t == Type::A)
        return std::make_shared<A>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    else if (t == Type::B)
        return std::make_shared<B>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    else
        assert(false);
}


No doubt, this doesn't work as the following call triggers a compilation error as the other branch for B doesn't have any constructor with single argument:
make_Type(Type::A,1);

gcc14 returns the following:
error: no matching function for call to 'B::B(int)'

I can create a static version with if constexpr. But how to attempt a runtime version? (Possibly without using typeinfo).
Any alternative approach is also welcome.

"No doubt, this doesn't work". I dunno, works fine for me. Show a [mcve], an example that actually exhibits the problem you need help with.

@IgorTandetnik: your first parameter is a compile time type, not defined at runtime. But even that works: https://godbolt.org/z/sP6zYPW96

@IgorTandetnik It won't work for the case make_Type(Type::A,1) as the other branch now doesn't compile as B doesn't have a compatible constructor taking single arg.

So, include that in the code shown in the question, along with the error message you are seeing.

Your types have different sets of constructor signatures, you know what exact signature you are going to use, but you don't know the type? This doesn't look like a real-life scenario.

Which signature will be used is not known apriori. It is known only at runtime. It is a situation where an object can be generated using alternate sets of data, which are like options, either specify a,b,c,d or specify a, e,f. Something like this. It is also not known which Type will be created. Just that it is some derived type of Base

"Which signature will be used is not known apriori. It is known only at runtime" At the point of call, the signature is known. It cannot be unknown, otherwise you cannot write the call. So you need to write down something like ...(intValue, doubleValue1, doubleValue2). Not a parameter pack or anything like that, but this specific call. Why can't you write B instead of ...?

You might be looking for something like this:
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> safe_make_shared(Args&&... args) {
    if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<T, Args&&...>) {
        return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}


template <typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<Base> make_Type(Type t, Args &&...args)
{
    switch (t) {
        case Type::A : return safe_make_shared<A>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        case Type::B : return safe_make_shared<B>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        default: assert(false); return nullptr;
    }
}

Demo
The idea is to have a safe_make_shared function that creates the object if the type is actually constructible with the given set of arguments, or returns null otherwise (or it could assert, or throw an exception as a fallback). The important part is that safe_make_shared can be instantiated with any set of parameters, but only attempts to pass the "right" set of parameters to the object's constructor.

the safe_make_shared seems to have solved the issue. the catch was the is_constructible_v. Thanks. I will check in detail.
